# Re-routing packets to private ip through public ip?

Tags: router, nat, lan

Many WiFi-routers have the feature to block LAN connections.
A router is configured to block traffic for private IP addresses 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x, 192.168.x.x except few like 10.0.0.1. Internet access is available for all computer on the network.
The packet will be terminated at router if the target address is one of those and packet is originating from IP address in the list.
Is it possible to communicate to those blocked IP addresses by sending packets to the public IP and then to the internal IP by using Network address translation?
The router will send the packet to the public IP router. Then the public IP router will send it to the internal address. The blocking conditions are not meet.
Is this a valid bypass?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about home routers, which are off topic here, they don't block private IPs, they block client to client traffic. But that is usually configurable-- you can turn that feature off.

Comment: They are organisation routers so I cannot turn that feature off. So, I am trying to figure out a bypass.

Comment: @fanix, unfortunately, questions about "_bypassing network security or policies_" are explicitly off-topic here, as are questions about networks that you do not control.

Comment: Can you suggest the appropriate stack exchange site to ask this questions?

Comment: @fanix, network engineers are not interested in helping you break into our networks.